# Test if SKSpriteNode is below another SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I'm making a game where a ball has to follow a certain path. If it goes off the path, they lose. The problem is that I can't figure out how to test if the ball is off the path. I tried to use `node.intersectsNode(background)` but since the background covers the whole screen it does not work.

One way I thought of would be to test if the path is under the ball. I don't know the code for this. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try comparing node positions ?

Answer (score 0):

If your path is a curve it wont work like that. The only case when you can compare node positions comparing to each other is when they approximately can be treated as rects (for example you can compare two circles if you treat them as squares). But I think your path is somewhat similar to a road so you have to check if your ball is still on it.

The thing I can advice you to start from is to take a look at TinyWings-clone tutorials, there are plenty of them in the web, they cover basics of using physics, and, what's more important, triangulation and working with polygons to detect collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this code I developed to **compare** the **positions** of your node in your update func. This method should allow to check whenever your Ball is somewhere very close to your other node.

Try out this!

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
super.update(currentTime)

if yourBall.position.x < yourOtherNode.position.x + yourBall.size.width / 2  && yourBall.position.x > yourOtherNode.position.x - yourBall.size.width / 2 && yourBall.position.y < yourOtherNode.position.y + yourBall.size.height / 2 && yourBall.position.y > yourOtherNode.position.y - yourBall.size.height / 2{
} else {
/* your function right here  if the ball loses track*/
}
```

I am still really new to coding so I hope this really "ugly code" works for you!